# WinForms Toolstip Items Size-To-Fit

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I am using a Toolstrip to draw myself a TabStrip where I do not want the items to overflow, but rather shrink-to-fit the available width. Very much like many browsers tabs behave (ex. Chrome).

I know there is a LayoutEngine property which can be overriden, but I have no clue on how to implement this.

Anyone knows how to make the items fit the toolstrips width?

Answer (score 0):

The Infragistics [.NetAdvantage](http://www.infragistics.com/Product.aspx?id=230) WinToolbars controls will do this. This is a commercial product, but it may be cheaper to buy a control than build one yourself.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion, but I rather not include a giant controls suite for this kind of, in my opinion, rather small issue. Now if I only could find an example on how to implement a LayoutEngine for a ToolStrip...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this related question:

[How to make a ToolStripComboBox to fill all the space available on a ToolStrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769087)

I prefer Martin's answer because it doesn't have any magic hard-coded numbers in it. While you'll still have to do a bit of arithmetic if you are making multiple items shrink-to-fit, I'm sure the same method would be applicable.